# What's is the most straightforward way to debug a breeze query on the server side?

Tags: odata, breeze

I have a non-standard BreezeController query which returns a "fake" IQueryable as a resource to query from the client using the standard breeze EntityQuery js class. This fake query builds up a collection of Entity objects mapped by Entity Framework and therefore known by breeze *in memory* and returns these as an IQueryable.

I have isolated the problem to be something to do with writing a projection query that's selecting a property that is populated in memory on the server as a Child collection of other instances of the same Entity type.

This query was working as of breeze 1.4.2. After upgrading to 1.4.6 (and related libraries), this query now returns an error response to the client: "The query specified in the URI is not valid".

I have stepped through the server-side query method in the BreezeController and see that the in-memory list of objects are being constructed without an exception being thrown. Once control passes back to breeze and the rest of the response pipeline something is occurring that causes the error response back on the client.

In order to investigate the problem further I need to step through more of the response pipeline but not sure how best to achieve this.

I have tried switching on the Visual Studio option "Enable .NET framework source stepping", but this doesn't seem to be able to locate/download sufficient number of the debug symbols to step into the things like Breeze, JSON, Web API, OData, etc.

I've tried configuring Visual Studio to break as soon as a CLR exception is thrown. But no exception appears to be thrown on the server side.

*I'm wondering if someone from Breeze can provide some advise?* **Maybe there are some additional code hooks in breeze I can write some of my own code to plug into simply so that I can set some breakpoints and further isolate the stage in the pipeline** that is having issues.

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A: How to debug a breeze query on the server.

Until such times as breeze publishes the .pdb files for each of it's dll's you will need to download the source from Github, compile, and manually copy the pdb files into the breeze NuGet package(s):

1. Download breeze source code

   - Browse to https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze
   - Download the version of the source code that matches the vs of breeze you need to debug (Tip: You will need to use the Branches button to select a specific tag)
2. Compile the breeze source code:

   - Open the VS solution file - Breeze.Build.sln
   - With Visual Studio open, change to Release build using the Configuration Manager dialog (this assumes you want to debug a set of *release build dll's* - the ones that Breeze.js publish in their NuGet)
   - Rebuild the solution - this will build an exact copy of the dll's within the breeze NuGet packages, *along with their assoicated .pdb files*
3. Copy the pdb files into the corresponding NuGet lib directory:

   - For example: \bin\Release\Breeze.ContextProvider.pdb -> packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.n.n.n\lib

Copying the pdb files into the NuGet package was the only way *I* could get Visual Studio to recognise and load the pdb files when wanting to step through. I tried loading the symbols by right clicking on the call stack frame but VS complained when I pointed to the pdb file in the breeze source code bin directory.

### Stepping through the breeze server side query

It looks the main body of interesting code that you want to debug is found in the `BreezeQueryableAttribute` and associated helper class `QueryHelper`. The easiest way I found to step into this code is to create a subclass of `BreezeQueryableAttribute` and within this subclass override the `OnActionExecuted` method. Decorate the IQueryable method
in the BreezeController with this new attribute.

With the new subclasses attribute in place, you can set a breakpoint on the `OnActionExecuted` in the subclass and step into the `BreezeQueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted` from there.

For convenience here's the subclassed attribute I created:

```
using Breeze.WebApi2;

public class DebugBreezeQueryable : BreezeQueryableAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

## A: Why did the projection query over a "fake" IQueryable fail after upgrading?

It was as I suspected: the `QueryableAttribute.ValidateQuery` was complaining about trying to $select an EF/breeze unmapped property (in this case a property named Children). It's interesting that this worked fine in vs 1.4.2 of breeze.

The workaround I came up with was to instead create a DTO class that is not mapped to the database and populate instances of these DTO's in memory from the Entity objects loaded from the database; to return these DTO's as an IQueryable. The key I believe is that these DTO classes are not mapped in EF/breeze.

For completeness here's an extract of the interesting code involved in the *failing* query:

**Client side query:**

```
query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("ScreenEntityUIs")
            .where("id", "==", parseInt(id, 10))
            .select("Id, EntityId, Children, AdditionalData, IsModal, IsList");
```

**Server side query:**

```
    public IQueryable<EntityUI> ScreenEntityUIs()
    {
        var sql = BuildEntityUIsQuery();
        var all = this.contextProvider.Context.Database.SqlQuery<EntityUI>(sql).ToList();
        var results = new List<EntityUI>();
        var roots = all.Where(p => p.ParentId == null);

        foreach (var root in roots)
        {
            this.BuildChildrenList(root.Id, all, root);
            results.Add(item);
        }

        return results.AsQueryable();
    }
```

**Entity class:**

```
public class EntityUI : StateInfo
{
    public EntityUI()
    {
        this.Children = new Collection<EntityUI>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<EntityUI> Children { get; set; }

    /* snip */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the relevant server side endpoint code and the client side query that it is trying to execute.

Per your 2nd question, the Breeze source is available on GitHub and you can download and debug directly into the Breeze EF libraries by changing your refs to point directly to downloaded versions of the source.

Comment: Cool, thanks Jay. I'll try and debug into what's going on first. If I can't figure it out then I'll post the code. If I do figure it out I'll answer my own question.

Comment: Jay, is there any reason why you don't distribute the pdb file along with the dll? If the pdb file was distributed then stepping through the breeze code would be possible without having to download and build sources ourselves.

Comment: It's a good idea. I'll add it to our internal list of features. Hopefully I can get this into one of the next few releases.